# How can set a Listener Interface implemented in every class?

Tags: java, swing, interface, actionlistener

I have build a Java Swing Application. Now I have this structure:

> class abstractNewOrder

```
public abstract class abstractNewOrder{

    ..
    ..
    ..
    public JComboBox comboBoxFornitore;

    public abstract void populateField(int row);
    public abstract void getDetail(Articoli articolo);

}
```

> This is PanelNewOrderClass

```
public class PanelNewOrder extends abstractNewOrder{

    public PanelNewOrder(){
        //TO DO
    }

    public void popolaCampi(int row) {
        //TODO
    }

    public void getDetail(Articoli articolo){
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Now I could have more class that extend abstractNewOrder, and I would like to that every class that extends this class (abstractNewOrder), must implements an actionListener for ComboBox, so I set for example

```
comboBoxFornitore.addActionListener(listener)
```

in the abstractClass and I'm sure that every class that extends that implements a Listener.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your `abstractNewOrder` could implement the `ActionListener` interface. This way, all non-abstract subclasses of this class are required to provide the implementation of the interface methods.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `abstract` method to `abstractNewOrder` that extending classes will have to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractNewOrder implements ActionListener
{
    public JComboBox<String> comboBoxFurniture;

    public AbstractNewOrder()
    {
        this.comboBoxFurniture = new JComboBox<String>();
        this.comboBoxFurniture.addActionListener(this);
    }

   //[...] Other methods you need [...]
}
```

Then just extend this class. The implementation of that Abstract class now must override the onActionPerformed() method.

Comment: This is the right answer to the question.
I would only add in the abstract class the empty declaration of onActionPerformed(), for clarity.